# File upload not working for all files

Tags: php

I'm using the code below to upload some files with allowed extension under 5MB. But using this code, all doc or pdf etc are not uploading!
For example: a 4.78MB docx file or a windows phone 1.64 mb jpg is not uploading!

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg","png","pdf","doc","docx","txt","rtf","bmp","psd","zip","rar","ppt","pptx");

$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));

if (in_array($extension, $allowedExts) && $_FILES["file"]["size"]<5242880 && $_FILES["file"]["error"]<=0) {
    $rand = rand(000,999);
    $tempfile = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $file = $time . "=" . $rand . "=" . $tempfile;

    if(file_exists("upload/".$file)) {
        header("location:home.php?error=error"); 
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/".$file);
    }
} else {
    header("location:home.php?error=error"); //this gets executed for some doc or pdf files !
}
```

Comment: What happens?  What's the error?

Comment: You're missing a `$` for `allowedExts` -- could that be the issue?

Comment: See the extension value when uploding them

Comment: you don't check extensions in case-insensitive manner, therefore extensions like `.DOC` will not be accepted

Comment: @AmalMurali sorry i missed $ while writing it here!

Comment: put the `var_dump($_FILES)` somewhere in that code so you can debug which files exactly don't get processed

Comment: Do you know where your got is stucked? Try to use `echo` or `file_put_contents`(with rapresentative names) to see the latest if block passed

Comment: @IvanHušnjak it gives: array
  'file' => 
    array
      'name' => string 'Holidays.docx' (length=13)
      'type' => string '' (length=0)
      'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'error' => int 1
      'size' => int 0

Comment: Where did you define `$time`? And is your 'upload' folder writable?

Comment: Also `$_FILES["file"]["error"]<=0` has no sense since the errors goes from 0 to 8

Comment: @putvande time is defined in the same file correctly and the upload folder is writable that's why it's accepting some files !

Comment: do you want any extension files can be upload?

Comment: @chiragode no only specified in $allowedExts !

Comment: @user2216267 Is it normal that almost all the file array fields are empty(such as size,length and others)? Have you tried `print_r($_FILE,true)` to see the content of the array?

Comment: @Dheed can i put bit relaxation on file error check by using erorr codes from 0 to 8 ?....because im concerned with is it in $allowedExt or not ?

Comment: You're combining three conditions in one statement. For troubleshooting purposes, change `if (in_array($extension, $allowedExts) && $_FILES["file"]["size"]<5242880 && $_FILES["file"]["error"]<=0) {` to `if (in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {` and see if it works. Repeat the same with the other two conditions and find out which one is failing

Comment: @user2216267 You have got 3 conditions inside the if statement, I don't know which one of them fail, you should separate them

Comment: @Dheed normal files are returning: array
  'file' => 
    array
      'name' => string 'sdcdoc.pdf' (length=10)
      'type' => string 'application/pdf' (length=15)
      'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\php7B3B.tmp' (length=23)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 11082

Comment: Has been uploaded this one?

Comment: @Dheed yes....i separated it in 3 if conditions....the last one is not executing !

Comment: The last one is the error code or the file_exist?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the last succesful executed if statement

Comment: yes..when the file is uploaded, its passed !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that file "Holidays.docx'" it seems to me that file exceeds `upload_max_filesize`. At least that is what the var_dump said about `$_FILES['file']['error']` which is equal to 1 ([UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php))

You should **chech php.ini settings** `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` because that is the actual limit of how large file can be uploaded to server. By default `upload_max_filesize = 2M` so your 5MB limit means nothing.

Also you can use `ini_get('upload_max_filesize');` to get runtime setting.
If you are unsure where is your php.ini configuration file located use `phpinfo()`.

Also to know about is that PHP will return `$_FILES['file']['size']` equal to 0 if file exceeds file size limit - which is exactly what happened.

So IMO everything is working as it should be. You should post more var_dump() infos for other files that don't upload.

Also to note, you don't check file extensions in case-insensitive manner so files with extensions like `.DOCX` will not be accepted by your script.

Comment: thanks, i have made changes for in case-insensitive comparison.... upload_max_size is 6MB & post_max_size is 8MB..the size if condition is passed by 4.78 mb docx file (checked by echo)....but not uploaded & shows array
  'file' => 
    array
      'name' => string 'Holidays.docx' (length=13)
      'type' => string '' (length=0)
      'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'error' => int 1
      'size' => int 0
!

Comment: @user2216267 hmm, that is strange if true. Try `var_dump(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));` - that will show you exactly what is the runtime value - might be that php.ini you looked is not actually in use

Comment: string '2M' (length=2) !...how is it possible as the upload_max_filesize in php.ini is 8MB ??

Comment: what distribution do you use? LAMP/WAMP/MAMP/XAMPP other?

Comment: it is possible you were looking at wrong php.ini file. place `phpinfo()` function in your code and check what is the configuration file used

Comment: im using WAMP....to change it i edited wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10\php.ini....where else should i edit ?

Comment: yeah, I figured that might be the case, there are actually three locations of php.ini files in WAMP. I think there should be one in /wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.10/bin -- that is probably the one that apache uses

Answer (score 3):

You're combining three conditions in your if statements here and if one of them fails, the `else` block will execute. But it won't tell you which condition failed.

```
if ( in_array($extension, $allowedExts) && $_FILES["file"]["size"]<5242880 &&
$_FILES["file"]["error"]<=0) {
```

Here:

- `in_array($extension, $allowedExts)` — from your `var_dump` output, this seems to be correct.
- `$_FILES["file"]["error"]<=0)` — this is okay, but you don't need to check if it is *less* than 0. The errors range from 1 to 8 and won't go below 0, but that won't be causing any issues though.
- `$_FILES["file"]["size"]<5242880` — this could be failing. Check your `php.ini` configurations and find out what `upload_max_size` is. If it's less than the filesize of your file, the condition will fail and the else block will execute.

For troubleshooting purposes, I'd recommend splitting the `if` statements in separate blocks. That way, you'll understand which part is executing and will help you find out why.

An example:

```
$check = True;
if (!condition) {
    $check = False;
}
if (!condition) {
    $check = False;
}
if (!condition) {
    $check = False;
}

if ($check == True) {
    # code...
}
```

---

Here are some other minor improvements for your code:

You're currently using:

```
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
```

to get the image extension. This could fail if the extension is in different case.

Change this to:

```
$extension = strotolower( end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"])) );
```

or better yet:

```
$extension = strtolower( pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION) );
```

Second, you're using `$time` variable in the following statement:

```
$file = $time . "=" . $rand . "=" . $tempfile;
```

That variable isn't defined anywhere and PHP will throw an `Undefined variable` error when you run the script. Change it to:

```
$time = time();
$file = $time . "=" . $rand . "=" . $tempfile;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks but i have defined $time variable in the same file.. upload_max_size is 6MB....the size if condition is passed by 4.78 mb docx file....but not the error condition....is there any other function for file upload or any way to upload with less restrictions ?

Comment: What do you mean by *less restrictions*?

Comment: i think the docx file is not uploading because it may not be in some "Standard" format....so maybe that's causing the file error to occur....so is the file is of allowed extension i wanted to upload without an hard checking (talking little generally) ?

Comment: You're not really checking the file type anywhere. The files extension doesn't always tell you the file-type. However, in this case, to find out why your upload is not working, split the if statements into multiple blocks. Find out the failing conditions and investigate why it's failing. See the updated answer.

Comment: i did in this way...but the $_FILES["file"]["error"]==0) is not executing !